# How do dynamically resize a image - CSS / HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

I'm trying to dynamically resize a .png image to whatever text is put on the box. As you can see from the printscreen it doesn't resize dynamically to fit the text in the box. I have no idea how to make it work ... the link to that page is here. I've tried formatting the padding, margins and adding classes and divs to that, but it didn't work. A link to the website can be found [here](http://bej.co/cleaning/html/services.php).
So the problem in the

`<div id='page' class='container'>`:

```
<div id="page-bg1">
   <div id="page-bg2">
      <div id="page-bg3">
         <div id="page" class="container">
        <div class="box-style2" id="content">
           <h2 class="title">Services</h2>
           <p>Our experience and business ethics have evolved over several decades of working in the cleaning industry. We understand the importance of supervision, training, communication, and customer satisfaction. The facility types we serve include commercial, healthcare, corporate, education, industrial, manufacturing, and auto dealerships
           </p>
           <h2>Building Maintenance Services:</h2>
           <ul>
              <li><b>Contract Custodial Cleaning:</b> Outsourcing of custodial cleaning is a way for corporate clients to reduce their direct costs while ensuring that quality control standards are met. We can work within your existing cleaning specifications or custom design a complete program for your nightly cleaning requirements, including all labor, cleaning equipment and complete supervision. Additional value-add features include consumable product inventory control, periodic project cleaning, and quality control site audits.  
              </li>
              <li><b>Certified Cleanroom Attendant Services: </b>
            Cleanroom cleaning is a highly-specialized function and critical part of our clients’ quality control standards. We can develop and implement a program that will conform to your protocols. Our Attendants are trained and certified in all areas of contamination control including waste removal, gowning procedures, cleaning techniques and equipment handling.
              </li>
           </ul>
        </div>
        <div id="sidebar">
           <div id="box2" class="box-style2">
             <h2 class="title">Specialized Cleaning Services</h2>
            <ul class="style3">
               <li>ESD and composition tile floor refinishing and maintenance</li>
               <li>Carpet and area rug cleaning</li>
           <li>Cubicle fabrics partition and upholstery cleaning</li>
               <li>Kitchen and cafeteria cleaning</li>
               <li>Window and glass cleaning</li>
               <li>Wall and ceiling cleaning</li>
            </ul>
               </div>
               <div id="box3" class="box-style2">
               <h2 class="title">Additional Services</h2>
               <ul>
                 <li><a href="#">Post-construction cleanup</a></li>
             <li>Temporary hourly-rate personnel</li>
             <li>Matron/day porters</li>
             <li>Pressure washing</li>
             <li>Painting</li>
             <li>Relamping</li>
             <li>Mold and mildew treatments</li>
             <li>Fabric and carpet soil protection</li>
             <li>Carpet deodorizing</li>
             <li>Floor mat purchase and rental programs</li>
             <li>Flame retardant applications</li>
             <li>Static control applications</li>
             <li>Seasonal school dormitory cleaning</li>
             </ul>
        </div>
         </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The `CSS` is here:

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}

body {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    background: url(palette/png/Background/bg.png) repeat left top;
    font: 14px/26px "Arvo", Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
    //color: #94856A;
   color: #0020C2;
}
a
h1, h2, h3 {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    font-family: 'Arvo', serif;
}

p, ol, ul {
    margin-top: 0px;
}

strong {
}

a {
    color: #789329;
}

a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
}

a img {
    border: none;
}

img.border {
}

img.alignleft {
    float: left;
}

img.alignright {
    float: right;
}

img.aligncenter {
    margin: 0px auto;
}

hr {
    display: none;
}

.image-wrapper {
    position : relative;
}

.scale-image {
    display : block;
    width : auto;
    max-width : 75% ;
}
/** WRAPPER */

#wrapper {
    background: url(palette/png/Background/bg.png) repeat left top;
}

#main-bg {
    background: url(palette/png/Background/bg_combined.png) repeat center top;
}

.container {
    width: 1000px;
    margin: 0px auto;
}

.clearfix {
    clear: both;
}

/** HEADER */

#header {
}

/** LOGO */

#logo {
    height: 183px;
    background: url(images/fmn_200.jpg) no-repeat center top;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

#logo h1, #logo p {
    margin: 0px;
}

#logo h1 {
    padding-top: 107px;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    line-height: 25px;
    font-size: 25px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}

#logo h1 a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}

#logo p {
    padding-top: 15px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    line-height: 14px;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #776D5C;
    background: url(image/fmn_200.jpg);
}

/** MENU */

#menu {
    height: 100px;
    background: url(images/crop.png) repeat center top;
}

#menu ul {
    height: 69px;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 31px 0px 0px 0px;
    list-style: none;
    line-height: normal;
    text-align: center;
}

#menu li {
    display: inline;
}

#menu a {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 30px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-decoration: none;
    line-height: 68px;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}

#menu a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}

/** PAGE */

#page-bg1 {
    overflow: hidden;
    background: url(palette/png/CBG/cbg_shadow.png) repeat-x left bottom;
}

#page-bg2 {
    background: url(palette/png/CBG/cbg_shadow.png) repeat-y center top;
}

#page-bg3 {
    background: url(palette/png/CBG/cbg_combined.png) repeat center bottom;
}

#page {
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 50px 0px 50px 0px;
}

.homepage #page {
    height: auto !important;
    height: 380px;
    min-height: 380px;
}

/** SLIDERTRON */

#slidertron {
    position: relative;
    width: 900px;
    height: 300px;
    margin: 0px auto;
}

#slidertron .viewer {
    width: 900px;
    height: 290px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#slidertron .reel {
}

#slidertron .slide {
    float: left;
    width: 640px;
    height: 260px;
    background: #FFFFFF;
}

#slidertron .slide img {
    padding: 9px;
    border: 1px solid #E4E2DE;
}

#slidertron .indicator {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 16px;
    cursor: default;
    user-select: none !important;
    -khtml-user-select: none !important;
    -moz-user-select: none !important;
    -o-user-select: none !important;
    -webkit-user-select: none !important;
}

#slidertron .indicator ul {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    list-style: none;
    text-align: center;
}

#slidertron .indicator li {
    display: inline;
}

#slidertron .indicator li.active {
}

#slidertron .indicator a {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
    margin: 0px 3px;
    background: url(images/slidertron_01.png) no-repeat -16px -258px;
    text-indent: -9999em;
}

#slidertron .indicator li.active a {
    background-position: 0px -258px;
}

#slidertron .navigation a {
    position: absolute;
    top: 1px;
    display: block;
    width: 125px;
    height: 258px;
    background: url(images/slidertron_01.png) no-repeat;
    text-indent: -9999em;
}

#slidertron .navigation a.previous {
    left: -1px;
    background-position: 0px 0px;
}

#slidertron .navigation a.next {
    background-position: 100% 0px;
    right: -1px;
}

/** CONTENT */

#content {
    float: left;
    width: 600px;
    padding-left: 50px;
}

.two-column2 #content {
    float: right;
    padding-right: 50px;
    padding-left: 0px;
}

#wide-content {
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0px 50px;
}

/** SIDEBAR */

#sidebar {
    float: right;
    width: 260px;
    padding-right: 50px;
}

.two-column2 #sidebar {
    float: left;
    padding-left: 50px;
    padding-right: 0px;
}

#sidebar .title {
    font-size: 18px;
}

/** FOOTER BLOCK */

#footer-block-wrapper {
    overflow:  hidden;
    padding-bottom: 40px;
}

#footer-block-bg {
    overflow:  hidden;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
    background: url(palette/png/Background/bg_bar.png) repeat-y center top;
}

#footer-block-bgtop {
    background: url(palette/png/Background/bg_bar.png) no-repeat center top;
}

#footer-block {
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 860px;
    height: auto !important;
    padding: 70px 70px 0px 70px;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #6C5F48;
}

#footer-block h2 {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px 0px 20px 0px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}

#footer-block #column1 {
    float: left;
    width: 240px;
    margin-right: 70px;
}

#footer-block #column2 {
    float: left;
    width: 240px;
}

#footer-block #column3 {
    float: right;
    width: 240px;
}

/** FOOTER */

#footer {
    padding: 50px 0px 70px 0px;
}

#footer p {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color: #2F2518;
}

/** BOX 1 */

#box1 .title1, #box1 .title2 {
    text-align: center;
}

/** BOX 2 */

#box2 {
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}


/** BOX STYLE 1 */

.box-style1 {
}

.box-style1 .title1 {
    padding: 0px 0px 5px 0px;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #FFFFFF;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 26px;
    color: #3C3223;
}

.box-style1 .title2 {
    padding: 0px 0px 15px 0px;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #FFFFFF;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 15px;
    color: #8A7C60;
}

/** BOX STYLE 2 */

.box-style2 {
}

.box-style2 .title {
    padding: 0px 0px 5px 0px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 26px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #3C3223;
}

.box-style2 .byline {
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: normal;
    color: #8B806F;
}


/** LINK STYLE 1 */

.link-style1 {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 48px;
    margin: 9px 0px 0px 0px;
    background: url(images/bio_2.png) repeat-x left top;
}

.link-style1 a {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 48px;
    background: url(images/bio_1.png) no-repeat left top;
    line-height: 48px;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-family: 'Arvo', serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}

.link-style1 span {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0px 30px 0px 30px;
    background: url(images/bio_3.png) no-repeat right top;
    color: #FFFFF;
}

/** LINK STYLE 2 */

.link-style2 {
    display: inline-block;
    background: url(images/homepage09.gif) no-repeat left 3px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    padding-left: 30px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #9F9788;
}

/** LINK STYLE 3 */

.link-style3 {
    background: url(images/homepage10.gif) no-repeat left 2px;
    padding-left: 30px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #9F9788;
}

/** LIST STYLE 1 */

ul.style1 {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    list-style: none;
}

ul.style1 li {
}

ul.style1 a {
    color: #6C5F48;
}

/** LIST STYLE 2 */

ul.style2 {
    margin: 0px 0px 10px 0px;
    padding: 10px 0px;
    list-style: none;
}

ul.style2 li {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 9px;
}

/** LIST STYLE 3 */

ul.style3 {
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    padding: 0px 0px;
    list-style: none;
}
```

The images which needs to be resized are `palette/png/CBG/cbg_combined.png` and `palette/png/CBG/cbg_shadow.png`, presented in the divs `#page-bg3`, `#page-bg2` and `#page-bg1`. That's the image that I wanted to resize according to the div text presented in that box.[image]. I'm also adding a screenshot so you guys can have an idea of the problem.

What can I do to make it work? I only need this central banner to be able to dynamically resize.
I'm also adding a screenshot of how I wanted the page to look like:
[image]

Comment: How do you want it to look? Can you share that screenshot too?

Comment: @DhirajShah I've added with the screenshot

Comment: Give me few mins. I will come up with a solution.

Comment: @DhirajShah Ok I'm working here too

Comment: This is what I have come up with as a quick solution. If this's ok with you, I will share the code.
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/23887590/Screen%20Shot%202014-02-22%20at%2011.11.31%20PM.png
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/23887590/Screen%20Shot%202014-02-22%20at%2011.11.34%20PM.png

Comment: @DhirajShah could you share the code with us?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, I have cropped your background and used it in a differnt way. You can get the images from the following link:

[#page-bg1](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/23887590/cbg_combined2.png) 
[#page-bg2](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/23887590/cbg_combined1.png) 
[#page-bg-3](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/23887590/cbg_combined.png)

And here's my code:

```
#page-bg1 {
  overflow: hidden;
  background: url(https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/23887590/cbg_combined2.png) center;
}

#page-bg2 {
  background: url(https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/23887590/cbg_combined.png) repeat-y center top;
}

#page-bg3 {
  background: url(https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/23887590/cbg_combined1.png) no-repeat center bottom;
}
```

Little Explanation: 
`#page-bg1` is the background behind and outside the box. 
`#page-bg-2` is a vertically repeating background inside the box where you put your content.
`#page-bg-3` is a backgroud with dashed border at the bottom of your content box which doesn't repeat but is always fixed at the bottom.